# Google Chrome: Not passing session to new open window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For months now we have been using code which opens a new separate window when a user logs in, passing specific options to make it pseudo fullscreen and remove whatever UI we can so we get as much of screen real estate for the app as possible.

Then with latest Chrome update something went wrong...

When people log in and the new window pops up and the old tab which launched the new window is closed, we are losing session. IF we left the parent tab open, it will work as normal. As soon as we manually closed that parent tab at any point in time even after doing 10 minutes of work on the child window, we lose session.

So how can we resolve this? Currently we are trying to keep users on previous version of Chrome where it still works fine, but this cannot last forever!

Code on how we open the child window:

```
var params = [
        'height='+(screen.availHeight-30),
        'width='+(screen.availWidth-12),
        'scrollbars=no',
        'resizable=yes',
        'status=no',
        'toolbar=no'
    ].join(',');
    var win = window.open('app-desktop.html', '_blank', params);
    win.moveTo(0,0);
```

One solution of course is to not close the parent tab, but this would be undesirable.

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons, but if you open a new window and close the old one, why open a new window at all?

Comment: How are you storing the session?

Comment: The session is created on a WebLogic server and passed around between client/server via cookie named JSESSIONID

Answer (score 0):

We're facing the same problem here. You have to launch chrome in app mode using --app=%url and then it works. But you lose control buttons.